# Send bash profile for ssh login

Tags: command-line, ssh, putty

At my work, I ssh into a lot of Linux boxes (using MTPuTTY on win 7, though I can use anything if need be, up to and including dual booting Linux).

We are not set up so that people's home directories are stored in a centralized network location. Each box gets its own home directory with its own bash profile. Naturally, this makes any sort of bash customization impractical.

Is there a way to get SSH to send the profile instead? Or any other way for me to store the profile in a centralized location so that it is used by all of my logins on all of the boxes? I have full admin rights on my workstation, but I can't make configuration changes on the remote boxes.

Comment: Do you have the option, as a one-time thing, of going through and inserting a `source` statement, sourcing a common profile from the network location, in each of the various individual profiles?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to source a profile from another host, that way you only need one host with your profile, wich in turn could be your workstation.

> source <(ssh name@yourhost cat .bashrc)

Comment: This executes without complaint and without apparent effect.